# Excel counta function fixed reach

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a planning sheet in Microsoft Excel 2010 for my company. I have made a screenshot of the planning sheet which you can see below. In the column CAP the planner can see how much capacity that week is left for Kees. The calculation for cell IW7, for example, works with the formula `=10-COUNTA(IX7:JB7)*2`. The problem is that when the planner, for example, cuts cell IX7 and pastes this in IU7, the formula becomes `=10-AANTALARG(IU7:JB7) *2` and a pop-up says there is a circular reference.<sup>1</sup>

How can the planner still cut and paste cells without Excel adjusting the referenced cells?
Or: How can I get a fixed reach of cells (f.e. IX7:JB7) even after cutting and pasting cells?

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

<sup>1</sup><sub>When a formula refers back to its own cell, either directly or indirectly, it is called a circular reference.</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the suggested answer [How do you force the focus of an Excel cell to remain the same?](https://superuser.com/questions/275004/how-do-you-force-the-focus-of-an-excel-cell-to-remain-the-same), with

> 10-COUNTA(**INDIRECT**(IX7), **INDIRECT**(JB7))*2

the refences stay the same when you cut and paste a cell.

Answer (score 0):

PasteSpecialValues rather than  Paste.

Comment: Explain what that means, please.

Comment: @Kevin Panko, he means instead of Paste (eg, Ctrl-v), do a right-click to bring up the menu and select "Paste As Special" and select "Value".  This will paste the value but not the formula therefore will not update if you make changes to cells IX7:JB7.  If that's not what you want, there is no easy way besides changing your formula in cell IW7 to `=10-COUNTA($IX7:$JB7)*2`.  Then you can copy and paste freely.

Comment: Neither PasteSpecialValues or $IX7:$JB7 works. When I cut the cell $IX7 and pastes this in $IU7, the reference $IX7 still changes into $IU7. PasteSpecialValues doesn't work neither, the option is not in the submenu Past Special. Now we have to copy the cell IX7, paste into IU7 and delete IX7. But I really want to cut and paste it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be named Ranges - This can also have the side effect of making the formula easier to understand.

```
=10-COUNTA(IX7:JB7)*2
```

would become

```
=10-COUNTA(Week50Projects)*2
```

And use the Name Manager to set a fixed reference to the cells, defining it as $IX$7:$JB$7